# How to convert 2 byte binary to an integer in c language

Tags: c, binary, unsigned-integer, iso8583

I am working in **ISO8583** format where i am getting length of message in a 2 byte binary format . I need to convert it into an integer using C . In C# this can be achieved by:

```
byte B1 = 0xFE;
byte B2 = 0xFC;

int r = (B1 << 8) | B2;
```

How we can do it in C. Please help

Thanks

Comment: Change `byte` to `unsigned char`. Exactly the same.

Comment: Thanks for the reply . I am getting data in this way ^A▒ which is not readable . Do i need to assign it to unsigned char Array and then take first element and second element and do this operation?

Answer (score 1):

It's almost the same as doing it in C#.
As mentioned above you change the byte type to a comparable c/c++ type.
You can use unsigned char or one of the int8 types: int8_t, uint8_t. For signed and unsigned.
The OR operation is exactly the same as in C#. I get the result to be 65276.
e.g.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int main() {

        uint8_t B1 = 0xFE;
        uint8_t B2 = 0xFC;

        unsigned int r = (B1 << 8) | B2;

        cout << r << endl;

        return 0;
     }
```